# Kmeans clustering in R combined with data.table package

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset that I wish to do kmeans cluster on.

Basically there're many ReEDSregion, and within each ReEDSregion there're many classes (ReEDSregion 1, class 1; ReEDSregion 1, class 2; ReEDSregion 2, class 1, etc.).

I want to do kmeans clustering with 10 clusters for the variable "grid_cost" for each ReEDSregion and class combination (by ReEDSregion and class).
Some ReEDSregion and class combo have less than 10 observations and hence will have as many clusters as the number of observations. I first created a function for that:

```
make_bins <- function (dtbl, nbins) {
  # we only need to cluster if there are more unique values for the grid cost than the number of bins desired
  if (dtbl[,length(unique(grid_cost))] > nbins) {
    bins <- kmeans(dtbl[, grid_cost], nbins)$cluster
  } else {
    unique_vals <- sort(unique(dtbl[, grid_cost]))
    bins <- dtbl[,which(unique_vals==grid_cost)]
  }
  return(bins)
}
```

And then I use data table to call the function:

```
nbins <- 10
scurve[, bin := make_bins(.SD, nbins), by=c("ReEDSregion", "class")]
```

But it shows error:

> Error in [.data.table(scurve, , :=(bin, make_bins(.SD, nbins)), by = c("ReEDSregion",  :
> Supplied 3 items to be assigned to group 8 of size 7 in column 'bin'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

What does this mean? can someone help me?

The version of my data table is 1.12.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the `else` part in your code, when you have less different values than bins.

You could use `factor` in this situation:

```
make_bins <- function (dtbl, nbins) {
  # we only need to cluster if there are more unique values for the grid cost than the number of bins desired
  if (dtbl[,length(unique(grid_cost))] > nbins) {
    bins <- kmeans(dtbl[, grid_cost], nbins)$cluster
  } else {
    bins <- dtbl[,dtbl[,as.numeric(factor(grid_cost))]]
  }
  return(bins)
}
```

Testing with `mtcars`:

```
m <- mtcars
setDT(m)
m[,grid_cost:=wt]

nbins <- 10
m[, bin := make_bins(.SD, nbins),by=c("cyl")]
m

     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb grid_cost bin
 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     2.620   1
 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     2.875   3
 3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     2.320   2
 4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1     3.215   4
 5: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2     3.440   7
 6: 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1     3.460   6
...
```